# All CSS properties don't transition smoothly

Tags: html, css, frontend

I created a CSS card design and added hover transitions to a few properties of the button at the bottom of the card. I added them for `background` and `color` properties. Unfortunately,  the hover animation is not smooth. The background color should transform smoothly in half a second like the text, but it happens immediately.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab";
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
}

.Cards {
    padding: 25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.Card {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
  
.Card-Image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 225px;
}

.Card-Content {
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    background: #BC4749;
}

.Card-Body {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    transform: translateY(-40px);
}

.Card-Title {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.Card-Description {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.Card-List {
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.Card-Button-Space {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.Card-Button {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}

.Card-Button:hover {
    background: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <link rel = "preconnect" href = "https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel = "stylesheet">
    <title>ItsMrVaibhav - Card Design</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "Cards">
        <div class = "Card">
            <img class = "Card-Image" src = "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?woods" alt = "Card Image">
            <div class = "Card-Content">
                <div class = "Card-Body">
                    <p class = "Card-Title">Card Title goes here</p>
                    <p class = "Card-Description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ex dicta fuga repellat, labore ab earum dolorum, nemo quidem doloribus?</p>
                    <ul class = "Card-List">
                        <li>First sentence</li>
                        <li>Second sentence</li>
                        <li>Third sentence</li>
                    </ul>
                  <p class = "Card-Description">Ipsam optio assumenda nam, ex dicta fuga repellat aliquid amet eligendi beatae? Deleniti pariatur suscipit exercitationem natus.</p>
                </div>
                <div class = "Card-Button-Space">
                    <button class = "Card-Button">Click to Learn More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you added transition to only Color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
transition: color 0.5s;
```

This line only makes any transition applied to the `color` property smooth. In order to make background transition smooth as well, you need to set it for all the properties. You can do that using the `all` keyword. Just change the above line to the following.

```css
transition: all 0.5s;
```

Additionally, you can also be specific and apply transition duration only to these two properties using the following snippet.

```css
transition-property: background, color;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
```

Using the `transition-property` CSS property, you can target specific properties.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab";
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
}

.Cards {
    padding: 25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.Card {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
  
.Card-Image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 225px;
}

.Card-Content {
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    background: #BC4749;
}

.Card-Body {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    transform: translateY(-40px);
}

.Card-Title {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.Card-Description {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.Card-List {
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.Card-Button-Space {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.Card-Button {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.Card-Button:hover {
    background: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <link rel = "preconnect" href = "https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel = "stylesheet">
    <title>ItsMrVaibhav - Card Design</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "Cards">
        <div class = "Card">
            <img class = "Card-Image" src = "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?woods" alt = "Card Image">
            <div class = "Card-Content">
                <div class = "Card-Body">
                    <p class = "Card-Title">Card Title goes here</p>
                    <p class = "Card-Description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ex dicta fuga repellat, labore ab earum dolorum, nemo quidem doloribus?</p>
                    <ul class = "Card-List">
                        <li>First sentence</li>
                        <li>Second sentence</li>
                        <li>Third sentence</li>
                    </ul>
                  <p class = "Card-Description">Ipsam optio assumenda nam, ex dicta fuga repellat aliquid amet eligendi beatae? Deleniti pariatur suscipit exercitationem natus.</p>
                </div>
                <div class = "Card-Button-Space">
                    <button class = "Card-Button">Click to Learn More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Vaibhav! I've been going crazy because of this for more than an hour.